# How to route to combine EJS engine with HTML + Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs, express, ejs

On a express js server, I am trying to combine :

1. (A) an integration of Passport using the EJS Engine
2. (B) HTML and Angular JS.

For (A), routing and authentication over routing is performed on the side of the EJS engine (/project/config/route.js).

For (B), routing is performed on the server.js (project/server.js) toward a subdirectory (/project/public/www/).

**Is it a way to redirect from (A) (/config/route.js) to (B) (/project/public/www) for certain pages in (B) using the EJS engine authentication route system but the technologies on (A)?**

Comment: I'm sure it's possible in one way or another, though i'm not sure how knowing that helps you.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, i am looking for some code showing multiple routing layers. Any chance you have some?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in two steps :

(1) modifying the EJS engine declaration
(2) Move all the route to secure pages on the EJS route file.

(1) On server.js :

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

(2) Then i moved all the routing into the EJS routing on (A).

And i access the elements of (B) from it, using the technology of (A).